# Fluid Dynamics and Pressure Difference

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, atmospheric-science

We all know that air is a fluid as it can blow and we say that the cause of this blow is pressure difference but my question is what creates this pressure difference? Is it related  to Earth's motion or something else?

Comment: Do you mean what causes "winds"?

Comment: What causes pressure difference for wind??

Comment: Please have a look at the Wikipedia article on winds - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wind; and then narrow down the question to a specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

The differences in pressure are caused by differences in heating of the air. A common example is the sea breeze:  In the absence of other effects, the land is heated during the day while the temperature of the ocean changes only slightly.  The warmer air expands, becomes less dense, rises, and exerts less pressure. It's replaced by cooler air flowing in from the sea.  At night, the process is reversed.

Comment: Why land becomes more hot than sea??

Comment: @Aakankshasharma because of the difference in heat capacity.

Answer (score 0):

It is a complicated process. But one of the reasons can be associated to a chimney effect.

Heated air expands to all directions, but the reaction from the surroundings is smaller above, because the pressure is smaller. So, it moves upwards.

Cold air flows horizontally and occupies the pressure depleted region. But when it also heats, the process continues.

Trade winds blows from higher latitudes to equatorial region. But have a component east to west due to coriolis acceleration.